# Are eigenspaces unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have calculated an eigenspace of a matrix. It is 2 dimensional. I checked it with WolframAlpha, but in WolframAlpha's solution one basis vector in this eigenspace is different from my solution.

Comment: Well, $ℚ^2$ is spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, but you could also take $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. Have you checked whether your spaces are equal at least?

Comment: The eigenspaces are unique. But the bases are not!

Comment: @k.stm No, I haven't. My other basis vector which is different from Wolfram's solution is an eigenvector too. But how do I check whether the spaces are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Doing it by hand, you can check that the two spaces are equal as in the following example.  Let
$$V={\rm span}\{(1,2,0),(3,5,1)\}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  W={\rm span}\{(7,8,6),(3,-4,10)\}\ .$$
Set up an augmented matrix and row-reduce:
$$\pmatrix{1&3&|&7&3\cr 2&5&|&8&-4\cr 0&1&|&6&10}
  \sim\pmatrix{1&3&|&7&3\cr 0&-1&|&-6&-10\cr 0&0&|&0&0\cr}\ .$$
Considering each of the two right hand sides separately, each has a solution as a linear combination of the vectors on the left hand side.  That is, $(7,8,6)$ and $(3,-4,10)$ are both linear combinations of $(1,2,0)$ and $(3,5,1)$.  So $W$ is a subspace of $V$.  You can now do the same sort of calculation "in the other direction"; more simply, since $W$ and $V$ have the same dimension they must be equal.